# Excel graph plotting - frequency of low cardinality column vs bins

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've 2 columns and a set of bin values.
Column A contains numeric random values. Column B (contains another property of column A) contains 'True', 'False', and blank cells, i.e 3 distinct values.

I need to plot a single graph as following:

X axis contains the bin values, e.g., 0, 250, 500.

3 curves showing frequency value for three distinct values of column B. B relates to bins through the medium of column A.

I think this type of graph would be a standard type graph. If so, please let me know the name.

Please either provide precise steps to plot it or provide a pointer which could help me plot this graph.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably create a new table with the values you would use to plot the graphics, using COUNTIFS function.
Something like:
Column D for bin values,
Column E for "True": `=COUNTIFS(A1:A100; "<0"; B1:B100; "True")`,
Columns F, G for "False" and "".
Then just plot it.

Now you can also use references to reduce your work.

You could write "True" to E1, "False" to F1, nothing to G1 and start your bins from the second row:
`=COUNTIFS(A1:A100; "<0"; B1:B100; E$1)` - that will allow to copy to functions from E to F and G.

There also is a hack to avoid explicitely writing "<100" for each bin: you should instead construct this string by `"<" & TEXT($D2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to create a histogram, it sounds like.  This is a standard Excel tool, though it is not in the standard toolbar because it is not as common as pie charts and the like.

Everything you need can be located [on Microsoft's website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214269/how-to-use-the-histogram-tool-in-excel).